# jq concat elements into 1 line

Tags: json, jq

I got below JSON example content.

```
{
   "pools":[
      {
         "id":"403add1f-25d9-4a24-99ff-12c5559fecfa",
         "loadbalancers":[
            {
               "id":"79970c9a-b0ba-4cde-a7e6-16b61641a7b8"
            },
            {
               "id":"ranj-b0ba-4cde-a7e6-16b61641a7b8"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "pools_links":[
      
   ]
}
```

I would like to have content as below

```
403add1f-25d9-4a24-99ff-12c5559fecfa#79970c9a-b0ba-4cde-a7e6-16b61641a7b8,ranj-b0ba-4cde-a7e6-16b61641a7b8
```

I have tried to use below, however, I want to concatenate the id into 1 line instead of having 2 lines.

```
.pools[] | "\(.id),\(.loadbalancers[] | .id)"
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
jq -r '.pools[] | .id + "#" + ( [.loadbalancers[].id] | join(","))'
```

For each item in `pools` it extracts the `id` field, and joins all the `loadbalancers[].id` fields.

Answer (score 0):

```
    // say, this is your json
    var json = "{\"pools\":[{\"id\":\"403add1f-25d9-4a24-99ff-12c5559fecfa\",\"loadbalancers\":[{\"id\":\"79970c9a-b0ba-4cde-a7e6-16b61641a7b8\"},{\"id\":\"ranj-b0ba-4cde-a7e6-16b61641a7b8\"}]}],\"pools_links\":[]}";
    
    var obj = JSON.parse(json),
        resultArr = [];
    
    obj.pools.forEach(function(pool){
        var id = pool.id,
            balancers = [];
        
        pool.loadbalancers.forEach(function(loadbalancer){
            balancers.push(loadbalancer.id);
        });
        
        var result = id+'#'+balancers.join(',');
        resultArr.push(result);
    });
    
    var joinResultsBy = '', // indicate any character to join the results by, if necessary
        finalResult = resultArr.join(joinResultsBy);
    
    console.log(finalResult);
```

Comment: I missed that. Well, then it's no help :)